# When I try to rebase git in VS-Code show rebase 2/165, what is that mean and how to reset it?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-rebase

I try to rebase the branch and in my vs-code, I show like this. How to reset to normal
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git rebase --abort` work for me